# Why is copy constructor called even when parameter is marked 'const'?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, constants, pass-by-reference, copy-constructor

Consider the following two functions:

```
int foo(const std::string x) {
    return x.length();
}

int foo2(const std::string& x2) {
    return x2.length();
}
```

When calling

```
std::string a("hello world!");
foo(a);
```

The compiler seems to still pass in a temporary object (created via copy constructor) to `foo` ( https://godbolt.org/z/p2ID1d )

Why does it do that? x is const, therefore it will not be changed by `foo`, therefore the compiler should still be able to pass directly `a` in the same way it does then calling `foo2(a)`.

Side note: I'm looking at the function types generated by godbolt:

```
foo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)

foo2(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

I'm guessing the answer has something to do with the fact that the `const` gets dropped in the definition of `foo`, but I have no idea why.  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: No it cant, youre passing it by value *it has to make a copy*

Comment: Const or no const, you are still passing by value, so the compiler is not wrong here by not doing this optimization. What if you are crazy enough to pass by (const) value and then cast the const off? Anywa, why bother doing this and count on the compiler optimizing it out for you? Why not just pass by ref, just like you did on the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is right to not optimize it. You could do something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


void foo(const std::string x) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    std::cout << x.length() << '\n';
}

int foo2(const std::string& x2) {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    std::cout << x2.length() << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::string a("hello world!");
    std::thread t1([&]{
        foo(a);
    });
    std::thread t2([&]{
        foo2(a);
    });
    a = "";
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This can even happen in the background and the compiler won't know.

Answer (score 3):

For non-reference parameters, `const` is actually ignored when the compiler stores the function's signature. For example, given this function prototype:

```
void func(std::string);
```

`func` can be implemented with this signature:

```
void func(const std::string) // This is NOT an overload.
{}
```

So `const` has no effect whatsoever on how value parameters are passed. They are copied. The `const` only has an effect on how the parameter is used within the function's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass by value, the compiler has to create a copy.

The effect of passing by `const` value is only that your function is not allowed to modify the copy it receives.  There is no benefit to doing this over passing by `const &` - on the contrary it's less efficient since it involves a copy.